# Prevent change original orientation in phonegap

Tags: angularjs, css, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ngcordova

I'm new in phonegap and I'm looking for a safe and easy way to detect if the device is a tablet or a phone.
My approach is this. If the width size is more than height size then the device is a tablet, otherwise is a phone. The problem with this approach is that if the phone start in horizontal position the result is wrong.

I need something, a property or a method in phonegap to get for the original size of the device regardless if it is horizontal or vertical position.

I'm using this:

window.innerHeight;
window.innerWidth;

or

window.height;
window.width;

But if I change the orientation then the property (height or width)change. I need the original size of the screen regardless if it is horizontal or vertical position.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this approach makes no sense, you are detecting if the device is in landscape or portrait, not if the device is a phone or a tablet.

Comment: Hi @jcesarmobile, thanks for your answer. Yeah, any idea? What is the easy way to to detect the device? Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no way of knowing. Why do you want to know it?

Comment: Oh. I'm using ionic also and you have a method "isIPad()" in order to know if the device is an ipad, but it doesn't work for me. I want to know this because I want to prevent the screen rotation only in a phone. I can force a vertical position in the config.xml, but it is for all devices. I´m trying with media querys now.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the org.apache.cordova.device plugin.

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/device/
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_device_device.md.html

It gives you getDevice() method which you can use the deduce the device type.

Include the plugin in your project:

phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.device

And it will be ready to use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I know that plugin and it hasn't a method to determinate if is a tablet or a phone. Do you know other approach? Or how can I block the screen rotation?. 

This property in the config.xml works ok: <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />, but the problem is that it is absolute. I need a horizontal orientation for tablets and vertical orientation for phones.